# How do I find the nth ancestor of a node in a binary search tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I got asked this at a job interview.  Here's my `O(log n)` solution.

Find the depth of the node.
Repeat the search, but stop at `depth - n`.

Is there a way to do this without the second pass?

Comment: Just remember the last *n* nodes.

Comment: You mingle `n` with number of items in the tree.  Was it intentional?

Comment: Note, that in many cases the interview problems are intentionally formulated incorrectly/incompletely, in order to see if you'll figure it out and ask the right questions, instead of rushing into writine the code. Given the above statement of the problem (assuming you reproduced it accurately), anyone who'd insist on a concrete code as a solution would automatically fail the question.

Comment: The problem is too vaguely stated to allow for a concrete solution. Until you clarify the problem, whatever solution is given to you here is a completely wild (and possibly irrelevant) guess. The missing critical parts include: 1) how is the node specified: by its key or by a physical pointer, 2) are there child->parent links in the tree. It is probably safe to assume that the answer to 2 is "no" (otherwise, the problem would be too trivial), but without a concrete answer to 1 there's no point to even start solving the problem.

Comment: @AndreyT: I guess I should have mentioned that the node is specified by its key.

Answer (score 3):

In your search for the node you can keep track of all nodes in the path from the current node to the root. This is a simple list with a length not greater than the depth of the tree. Once the node has been found, its *n*th ancestor is at position *length - n* in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for the node and save the path as you follow it. Roughly this (for a tree of ints):

```
Node* nthAncestor(Node* root, int target, int n)
{
    Node* list[n];
    int pos = 0;
    Node* node = root;
    while(node->value != target)
    {
        list[pos] = node;
        pos = (pos + 1) % n;
        if(node->value < target)
            node = node->left;
        else if(node->value > target)
            node = node->right;
    }

    return list[(pos + 1) % n];
}
```

Please note that I assumed the nth ancestor *does* exist.

For a tree of size T this runs in `O(log T)` time and uses `O(n)` space (*n* as in *n*th ancestor).

Comment: Is the semicolon after the `while` intended?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit wrong, I guess.  You miss one important matter. Of course you can do it without second pass.  Just maintain a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) of last n nodes in your search.

What you miss is that such algorithm needs `O(log n)` memory.  While your solution trades off time consumption for memory usage, and uses `O(1)` (constant amount) of additional memory)

So your solution is not "wrong" or "too slow".  It just has its own pros and cons.

Comment: The queue can be even worse than that, requiring O(n) for a completely unbalanced tree that has devolved into a linked list.

If you're OK with potentially O(n) memory, you may also consider a flat array of size N to hold your traversal history.  That also avoids the O(N) (for a singly-linked list) or O(k) (for a doubly-linked list) traversal to find the kth ancestor after the target has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it occurs ot me that an easy way that requires only a single extra node or less in space would be to have a dummy node that holds the backtrack count. When you find the search target, you then set the dummy node to *n* and return *it*, not the node you found which you don't want.

You need a function `DUMMY(node)` that returns true only for the dummy node. (`DUMMY()` could be implemented by comparing the node address or by checking for a magic cookie inside the node.)

```
Node *search(Node *next) {
  if (found the the answer)
    dummy->backtrack = n;
    return dummy;
  } else r = search(whatever ? n->left : n->right);
  if (DUMMY(r)) {
    if (dummy->backtrack == 0)
      return next;
    --dummy->backtrack;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: Technically, this doesn't use *just* the space of one extra node... You're forgetting the stack space you're using with recursion.

Comment: hehe, ok, I suppose I could have said *additional* space

Answer (score 1):

Use an n-spaced queue for this. Whenever you find one, deque and enque,

```
findnth(node *root, queue q, int n, int number)
{
   if(!root || !q) 
      return;
   findnth(root->left,  q, n, number);
   if(root->d == number) {
      if(q.size() < n) {
         nth ancestor not exist;
         print q->deq() as q.size() ance return;
      }
      else
         print q.deq()
   }
   if(q.size() < n) {
      q.ins(node->data);
   }
   else {
      q.deq();q.enq(node->data);
   }
   findnth(root->right,  q, n, number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done without the second pass. You just need to use two pointers. Here's how you can do it

1. Using a pointer p1,starting from the root, search for the node whose ancestor is to be found. But you go only n steps down.
2. Now when you reach n steps down, start another pointer p2 from the root, that also searches for the same node.
3. Move the both pointers in lock step, such that they both go down one level together. When p1 reaches your node, p2 will point at the nth ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this function might help ... 

function printAncestor(node *root , node *search , int *k)
{
  if(!root)
   return 0;
  if(root == search)
   return 1;

  int p1 ,p2;
  p1 = printAncestor(root->left , search , k);
  p2 = printAncestor(root->right , search , k);

 if(p1) {
   (*k)--;
if(*k >0)
   printf("%d ",root->left->value);
return 1;
 }
if(p2)
{
  (*k)--;
  if(*k >0)
  printf("%d ",root->right->value);
return 1;
}
}
```

The logic behind this is that , we go until the search node from the root via recursion.When we find it , we traverse along the path that it came from and print it.